# Calculating ROC and AUC in loop

Tags: r, machine-learning, predict, roc, auc

I created several models for a binary classification problem and I'd like to calculate and plot the AUC and the ROC for each model (ideally in *one* plot). How could I do this?

This is the code I currently use:

```
library(pROC)
model <- load_model_hdf5('M1.h5')
pred <- model %>% predict(test[,1:10]) 
roc_object <- roc(test[,11], pred) # create ROC curve
auc(roc_object) # calculate area under curve
```

`test[,1:10]` is the test data and `test[,11]` is the ground truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sample data of `mtcars`, I have created an example involving several ROC in one single plot.

After your first call to `plot()`, the subsequent calls using `lines()` will append to the existing plot instead of creating a new plot.

```
data(mtcars)

roc1 <- roc(mtcars[, "am"], mtcars[, "mpg"])
roc2 <- roc(mtcars[, "am"], mtcars[, "disp"])
roc3 <- roc(mtcars[, "am"], mtcars[, "hp"])

plot(1 - roc1[["specificities"]], roc1[["sensitivities"]], type = "l", col = "green")
lines(1 - roc2[["specificities"]], roc2[["sensitivities"]], col = "blue")
lines(1 - roc3[["specificities"]], roc3[["sensitivities"]], col = "red")
```